# Importing typescript definitions for my bundled javascript library

Tags: node.js, typescript, webpack, typescript-typings

I have a library I wrote in typescript, it contains multiple files and an index.ts file that contains all the exports of the library.

I used webpack to compile the entire library into a single index.js file but I'm having trouble importing it WITH type definitions.

Lets say this is my library:

```
src
-- index.ts
-- items-dal.ts
-- items-bl.ts
output
-- index.js
-- index.d.ts
-- items-dal.d.ts
-- items-bl.d.ts
webpack.config
ts.config
package.json
```

So I copied the output folder to my other project but when I try to create a class that inherits one of my library's classes I get an error:

```
// user-dal.ts
const { ItemsDAL } = require("./output");

class UsersDAL extends ItemsDAL {
  constructor() {
    super("users");
  }
}

export default new UsersDAL();

// usage
import usersDal from "./users-dal.ts";
usersDal.getAll() // <-- Property "getAll" doesn't exist on type usersDal
```

I know I can work around this by using require() but I'd prefer having the actual typings in my other projects.

The reason I'm doing this is because I'm obfuscating the index.js file but I don't mind exposing the name of the functions it contains. It may sound counter-productive but it provides enough security for my needs.

Is there a way to make typescript detect the d.ts files? (or any other way to have obfuscated code with typings)

Answer (score 0):

Just add a [`"types"` declaration to your `package.json`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/publishing.html#including-declarations-in-your-npm-package).

```
{
  ...
  "main": "./output/index.js",
  "types": "./output/index.d.ts",
  ...
}
```